# Positioning several text items over an image

Tags: html, css

What is the easiest way (using css) to position several separate text items over the top of a single image?

I've got the following:-

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

with the CSS:-

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

But that doesn't work because all of the text items are on top of one another.
Is the best way to do it with a list? Or is there another way?

Comment: Is using a background image possible?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
div { position:relative; }
div img { position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }  
div p { position:relative; z-index: 2; }
```

But this way the div will take the height of the text, not the image.

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/mydQ9/)

```
div { 
    position: relative;
}

div img { 
    position:absolute
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:#fff;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> OK, that seems to work - but how do I make sure the text items are all
>   contained within the confines of the image? Is that even possible?
>   Ideally, I'd like to make the text items appear in two parallel lists.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/mydQ9/1/)

You'd need to set the size of the container `div` to that of the `img`. From then, you can control how you want to handle the overflow.

You can use `float:left; width:50%;` on your `p` so they display in two columns.

Comment: OK, that seems to work - but how do I make sure the text items are all contained within the confines of the image? Is that even possible?

Ideally, I'd like to make the text items appear in two parallel lists. (Sorry, probably should have mentioned that before - one step at a time!)